# asp.net mvc Bundle.IncludeDirectory example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

Hi Can anyone give me an example on how to use Scriptbundle method IncludeDirectory for Javascripts,
not able to get how to write the search pattern string , Is it regex?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customjs").IncludeDirectory(
                "~/Scripts/Custom",?);
```

Comment: Here are some other examples / explanation from a related [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563415/force-asp-net-mvc-bundle-to-render-the-javascript-files-in-a-certain-order/14563828#14563828).

Comment: Thanks Mike , the example gives more information

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customjs").IncludeDirectory(
                "~/Scripts/Custom","*.js"));
```

If you want for example javascript.

You can read more here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Why will the above also include files that end with .coffee? Should it not send only *.js?

Comment: If you need certain files from the folder to be included before others, you can specify them separately with Include (called before IncludeDirectory) , even though they will be picked by the "*.js" search pattern as well - the system is smart enough to include them only once.